# How can i convert xml soap request to DOMDocument using symfony 3.4

Tags: xml, symfony, dom, soap

I am trying to convert xml code to Dom 
I created successfully soap create, update, delete requests it's working everything fine, problem is xml code readability little difficult, now i decided to convert xml to dom

Create Action:

```
/**
 *  Returns the soap create body for the Newsletter Entity.
 * 
 * @param Newsletter $newsletter
 * @param type $action
 * @return string 
 */
public function getSoapCreateNewsletterBody(Newsletter $newsletter) {

    $soapBody = '
     <Create xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services">
                <entity xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                    <b:Attributes xmlns:c="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic">' .
            $this->getFieldXml(self::STRING_TYPE, $newsletter->getEmail(), 'new_email') .
            $this->getFieldXml(self::STRING_TYPE, $newsletter->getName(), 'new_name') .
            '</b:Attributes>
                    <b:EntityState i:nil="true"/>
                    <b:FormattedValues xmlns:c="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic"/>
                    <b:Id>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</b:Id>
                    <b:LogicalName>new_newsletter</b:LogicalName>
                    <b:RelatedEntities xmlns:c="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic"/>
                </entity>
                </Create>';

    return $soapBody;
}
```

Delete Action:

```
 /**
 * Returns the soap delete body for th Newsletter Entity
 * 
 * @param Newsletter $newsletter
 * @return string
 */
public function getSoapDeleteNewsletterBody(Newsletter $newsletter){

       $soapBody = '
              <Delete xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services">
                 <entityName>new_newsletter</entityName>
                 <id>' . $newsletter->getNewsletteridcrm() . '</id>                      
              </Delete>';

    return $soapBody;
}
```

Here i am trying to convert xml to dom, issue with below code

```
/**
 * Returns the soap delete body for th Newsletter Entity
 * 
 * @param Newsletter $newsletter
 * @return string
 */
public function getSoapDeleteNewsletterBody(Newsletter $newsletter){

    /* Generate the DeleteRequest message */
    $deleteRequestDOM = new DOMDocument();
    $deleteNode = $deleteRequestDOM->appendChild( $deleteRequestDOM->createElementNS( 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services', 'Delete' ) );       
    $deleteNode->appendChild( $deleteRequestDOM->createElement( 'new_newsletter', $newsletter ) );
    $deleteNode->appendChild( $deleteRequestDOM->createElement( 'id', $newsletter->getNewsletteridcrm()->ID ) );
    /* Return the DOMNode */
    return $deleteNode;     
}
```

can anyone tell me how can i do this...
Thanks in advance ...

Updated Working code:

```
/**
 * Returns the soap delete body for th Newsletter Entity
 * 
 * @param Newsletter $newsletter
 * @return string
 */
public function getSoapDeleteNewsletterBody(Newsletter $newsletter){

    /* Generate the DeleteRequest message */
    $deleteRequestDOM = new DOMDocument();
    $deleteNode = $deleteRequestDOM->appendChild( $deleteRequestDOM->createElementNS( 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services', 'Delete' ) );       
    $deleteNode->appendChild( $deleteRequestDOM->createElement( 'entityName', 'new_newsletter' ) );

    $deleteNode->appendChild( $deleteRequestDOM->createElement( 'id', $newsletter->getNewsletteridcrm()) );
    /* Return the DOMNode */

    return $deleteRequestDOM->saveXML($deleteRequestDOM->documentElement);
}
```

Comment: Can you please describe the "issue with below code" a little further? What is the actual result? What are you expecting? Are you facing an error message or exception?

Comment: @nifr thanks for quick response issue is this line $deleteNode->appendChild( $deleteRequestDOM->createElement( 'new_newsletter', $newsletter ) );    here error is Warning: DOMDocument::createElement() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given

Comment: Can you see above create and delete actions both working properly i need to convert xml code to DOMDocument can you help me how to convert xml to dom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is caused by this line:

```
$deleteRequestDOM->createElement( 'new_newsletter', $newsletter )
```

Here `$newsletter` is a `Newsletter` object but `createElement` expects a string as second argument (the value of the XML element). Have a look at the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/de/domdocument.createelement.php) of the function.

What you really want is ...

```
$deleteRequestDOM->createElement('entityName', 'new_newsletter')
```

... to create this XML Node:

```
<entityName>new_newsletter</entityName>
```

Comment: thank you so much ... i realized now one more issue in query no problem i resolve this ... [Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class DOMElement could not be converted to string] , any way thank you so much your support

Comment: You need to return a string from the function. That'd be - in your case - `return $deleteRequestDom->saveXML();` to return the XML as a string.

Comment: Thank you so much your valuable support @nifr  ... working fine